# css3 animation.css not working with custom modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, animate.css

I was trying to create my own Full page modal and I got success in that but now I want to add a animation to it... am using [animate.css](https://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/6gqkc2vo/) to achieve this task but the animation is not working only when add a zoomIn or zoomOut animation class

here is [JSFiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/6gqkc2vo/) what I tried... any help be appreciated...

My Html

```
<div class="am-modal" id="examples-modal">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="am-colse"> Back</a>
  <div class="head">
    Trying Modal with zoonIn and out effect
  </div>

</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="am-modal-trigger" data-am-target="#examples-modal">Modal Trigger</a>
```

Css

```
.am-modal {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  padding : 20px;
}
.am-modal a{
  float : float;
}
.head{  
  margin-top : 40px;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #fff;
  text-align : center;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  resizeDiv();
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    resizeDiv();
  }

  function resizeDiv() {
    vpw = $(window).width();
    vph = $(window).height();
    $('.am-modal').css('height', vph + "px");
  }

  $('.am-modal-trigger').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('am-target');
    $(target).css('display','block');
    $(target).addClass('zoomIn');
  });

  $('.am-colse').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('zoomIn').addClass('zoomOut');
    $(this).parent().css('display','none');
  });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrx3uyzb/1/) You need to add class "animated"

```
<div class="am-modal animated" id="examples-modal">
```

Trying Modal with zoonIn and out effect

Answer (score 1):

When you add the zoomIn class to your modal are you being sure to add the `animated` class? This worked on the JSFiddel you provided:

```
<div class="am-modal animated zoomIn" id="examples-modal">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="am-colse"> Back</a>
  <div class="head">
    Trying Modal with zoonIn and out effect
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks dude I was forgotten to add that only